# Blade view 'has stack' condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to check from a parent layout if a children push something.

In the same way that I check with `View::hasSection('section-name')` with [hasSection](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/View/Concerns/ManagesLayouts.html#method_hasSection) method. I'm looking for something like : `hasStack`.

The purpose is to this :

```
@if(/* has stack 'foo' */)
    <div id='foo'>
        @stack('foo')
    </div>
@endif
```

What is the best way to do it?

*[Note] I'm dealing with Laravel 5.4*

Comment: "a mother layout"..?

Comment: @voodoo417 A blade template that I'm going to extend. What is the name for it?

Comment: Think, it is called "parent layout" ^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Laravel 7 and the following works to check for pushed content:

```
@if($__env->yieldPushContent('foo'))
   
    <p>There is something in the "foo" stack.</p>

@endif
```

You could put this into a [custom blade directive](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#custom-if-statements):

```
    Blade::if('hasStack', function($stackName) {
        return !empty(view()->yieldPushContent($stackName));
    });
```

and use it like:

```
@hasStack('foo')

    <p>There is something in the "foo" stack.</p>

@endhasStack
```

Just beware - the @end part does not camelCase the directive name so it's @endhasStack, not @endHasStack.

Comment: I can't test if your solution works because I asked this question 3 years ago, but I validate the answer with the hope that can help someone.